# Cambiar el tamaño del nav en Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Estoy haciendo un sitio en Vue.js, y quiero poner en práctica el típico efecto de resizing del nav al hacer scroll.
Tengo un método para ello, y otros dos *listeners* del scroll.
El tema es que no reconoce el elemento `nav`, y me da el siguiente error en la consola (todas las veces que se hace scroll): `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null`. No entiendo por qué, ya que he definido mi constante.

**`Header.vue`:**

```
export default {
  name: 'header-app',
  methods: {
    resizeOnScroll: function () {
      const nav = document.querySelector('site-header')
      if (this.scrollY >= 20) nav.classList.add = 'scroll'
      else nav.classList.remove = 'scroll'
    }
  },
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.resizeOnScroll)
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.resizeOnScroll)
  }
}
```

**`Header.html:`**

```
<b-navbar class="site-header" id="navbar">
    <b-container>
        <b-navbar-brand href="#">
            <img class="logo" src="../../assets/logo.png" alt="Site logo">
        </b-navbar-brand>
        <b-navbar-nav>
            <div class="icons">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/appsa" target="_blank"><i class="icon-google-play"></i></a>
            </div>
        </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-container>
</b-navbar>
```

**Estructura del proyecto**

```
|- build
|- config
|- dist
|- node_modules
|- src
   |- assets
   |- components
      |- Header
         |- Header.vue
         |- Header.html
         |- Header.scss
   |- router
   |- sass
   |- App.vue
   |- main.js
|- static
|- .babelrc
|- .editorconfig
|- .eslintignore
|- .eslint.js
|- .gitignore
|- .postcssrc.js
|- index.html
|- package.json
```

Comment: Sí, es la clase que tiene mi elemento en el HTML.

Comment: Ahí agregué el HTML. Es todo lo que hay. El SCSS no tiene sentido.

Comment: Sí, es Vue2, usé el template de webpack. Si podés explayarte en una respuesta, te lo agradezco!

Comment: Puedes adjuntar la estructura de tu proyecto.

Comment: Sí, estoy usando bootstrap-vue. @bercklynCarlosviza en breve publico la estructura. Saludos!

Comment: Ok.. fijate toda la info que le faltaba a la pregunta ;)... bootstrap-vue tiene incluido la reduccion del navbar en una propiedad.. ahora la buscamos ;)

Comment: Ok, gracias. Busqué antes esa funcionalidad en BV y no la encontré. ¿Me estoy perdiendo algo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno la cosa es asi..

Hay que hacer varios retoques, pero se puede hacer casi sin preocuparse por buscar el elemento en el DOM, cosa que en general VUE resuelve automaticamente.

Lo que vamos a hacer es por pasos:

- Agregar a la navbar la propiedad Sticky

  ```
  <b-navbar sticky>
  ```
- Agregarle a la navbar una clase propia, la que va a controlar la propiedad en el CSS.

  ```
  <b-navbar sticky v-bind:class="{shrink:Escroleando}">
  ```
- Agregar la propiedad Escroleando al modelo:

  ```
  data() {
      return {
          Escroleando: false,
          ....
      }
  },
  ```
- Cambiar la funcion Scroll a lo siguiente:

  ```
  methods: {
      resizeOnScroll: function () {
          if (window.scrollY  >= 20) {
              this.Escroleando = true
          }
          else {
              this.Escroleando = false;
          }
      },
      .....
  }
  ```

  O mucho mas lindo algo asi:

  ```
  resizeOnScroll: function () {
      this.Escroleando = (window.scrollY >= 20);
  }
  ```
- Y agregar el style correspondiente..

  ```
  <style>
      nav.navbar.shrink {
          max-height: 35px;
      }
  </style>
  ```

Reutilice tus funciones create y destroyed, y con eso cuando haces scroll, la barra se achica. Obviamente hay que trabajar sobre el CSS, pero basicamente hace lo que queres.

Agrego un link, con un projecto de ejemplo [ACA](https://github.com/topcatarg/VueShrinkNavBar)

Comment: Excelente, primero te agradezco por tomarte el tiempo para formular la respuesta y ayudarme, @gbianchi. Estoy poniendo en práctica tu solución, pero no logro ver que cambie la barra de tamaño. Cuando decís de agregar al `navbar` la propiedad sticky, te referís a poner directamente `position: sticky`? Actualmente está `fixed`. Eso es lo único que tendría distinto. El resto estoy haciendo todo exactamente igual.

Comment: tiene que ser sticky. si esta fixed, se va a perder cuando scrolees. Prueba cambiar a sticky, y si te genera otra duda vemos.. ah.. y ahora edito el codigo, el sticky no esta!

Comment: Creo que también en la parte de los estilos estás usando `navbar` como una clase, y en el HTML está con `id`. Sigue sin funcionarme. El método `resizeOnScroll` lo saqué de los métodos, está ok?

Comment: no. el metodo resizeonscroll va en los metodos.. en el ejemplo que probe anduvo todo asi.. espera que aclaro eso tambien... el id del navbar no importa. Pero saquesmolo.. aca no lo tengo..

Comment: Todavía sigue sin funcionar. Ni siquiera veo que se agregue la clase `shrink` al elemento en las Developer Tools. A veces los elementos de Bootstrap son difíciles de sobrescribir. Tendrá que ver con eso? (Muchas gracias de antemano)

Comment: No no. Lo probe con  bootstrap vue. Yo aca veo como mi barra se achica y como se agrega la clase cuando hago el scroll... porbaste hacer unoa console debug? Para ver si pasa por el codigo? Es mas yo lo hice en un componente

Comment: @TheWoodStudio te agregue un ejemplo en git (el link esta en la respuesta). Si eso no es lo que queres, avisame!

Comment: Excelente! Había borrado `created()` y `destroyed()`, pero claro, de esa manera nunca iba a tener el trackeo del evento scroll. Te agradezco mucho! Por tu tiempo, y por compartir tus conocimientos!